# Cannot access document's title element with jQuery (IE 8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-8, title

I'm seeing this issue in Internet Explorer 8, but not in Safari or Firefox.  So far, I have not tested in other IE versions.

I am developing my own jQuery plugin and, for this question, I've stripped it down to the two relevant lines.

---

In IE 8, using the code below, `$('title').text()` does not do anything.  `docTitle` is blank because `title` is blank, as if the jQuery selector for `<title>`, `$('title')` is not working.  (Again, AFAIK, this is just in IE 8)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {

        var title = $('title').text(),
            docTitle = escape(title);

    };
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/YMBQ2/

---

However, using the plain JavaScript code below, `document.title` is working fine in everything including IE 8...

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {

        var docTitle = escape(document.title);

    };
})(jQuery);
```

---

**EDIT:**

It does not matter that this code is inside a plugin.

Same result in IE 8 with this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var title = $('title').text();
    alert(title);
});
```

Just to clarify, I am not insisting on using this.  In fact, I fixed my plugin by simply using `document.title` instead.  **If it wasn't clear initially, I'm just asking why this does not work in IE 8.**

---

Can anyone explain **why**, or what stupid mistake I may have made here?

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here are some jQuery Bug reports on this issue

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7025

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5881

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2755

And dozens of others reporting the same thing.  The official response is to state, *"`document.title` is the only reliable cross-browser way and should be used instead"* and the Ticket is closed.  So there you go.

Comment: Perhaps trying to use jQuery for something that is a simple property access? ;-p

Comment: @RobG, maybe it's not efficient... I really don't know... but it's a jQuery plugin after all.  None of that really explains why it doesn't work in IE 8.

Comment: @Kris Ivanov, finding a workaround is not the issue here. - Also, `document.title` is the method recommended by jQuery people when closing bug reports.

Comment: that is not a workaround, what you need is the innerHTML of the element, also "Markup is not permitted in the content of a TITLE element"

Comment: @Kris, you are missing the whole point.  Quoting myself: _"...I'm just asking **why** this does not work in IE 8."_

Comment: @Kris, what does _"Markup is not permitted..."_  have to do with anything?  My original code was only trying to _retrieve_ the content within the document's title element.

Comment: the point is it does not matter why it does not work, each browser implements things different, I suggest you to use `document.title`; always opt in of using native ways than jQuery selectors, much faster

Comment: @Kris - it does matter to the OP. Understanding quirks (in both IE and jQuery) matters. The OP knows about `document.title` but wanted an explanation of the quirk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess jQuery iterates over all TextNodes and concatenates its nodeValue. IE stores this value differently than other browsers.

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[ 0 ];
title.firstChild // This would be the Text-Object with the characterdata of the title
                 // Firefox: [object Text]
                 // IE: null
```

This should be the reason you cannot get the textContent with `jQuery.text()`. `title.text` seems to be cross browser comp. I only tested it in IE 7 and Firefox 3.6 but [you can check the other browser](http://jsfiddle.net/fw4zC/) if you like. But why not using `document.title`?

Comment: I **am** using `document.title`.  I just wanted to know why `$('title').text()` does not work in IE 8.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Sazoier has the answer. jQuery gets an element's text cotent by iterating over nodes and getting text from the text nodes (see line 4734 in v1.6.2). IE < 9 doesn't have any text nodes inside the title element (for reasons known only to Microsoft) so jQuery fails to get the content. It's either a bug in jQuery or a design failure as it is trying to normalise the text content across different browsers using a method that fails in one of its "supported" browsers.

Comment: @RobG, I agree.  My initial comment was only in response to his question, _"But why not using document.title?"_  I'm going to let this sit a bit and then I'll likely accept his answer.

Comment: @Saxoier, can you clarify your statement,  _"title.text seems to be cross browser comp"_?  Perhaps you meant to say that it does **not** seem to be cross-browser?

Comment: @Sparky672: `title` refers to `document.getElementsByTagName('title')[ 0 ]` not `$('title').text()`. `document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].text` works fine in Firefox 3.6; IE 5.01, 5.5, 6 (all [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)), 7 (native); Opera 9.64, 11.52; Opera Mobile 10. OS: Win XP

Answer (score 0):

try using `$('title').html()` which should work in all browsers

Comment: And `document.title` works in all browsers, but neither answers the original question.