# $('title').text() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the page title using jQuery, But it doesn't work in IE, Why?

The code like this:

```
alert( $('title').text() ); // empty in IE
$('title').text('Some Text!'); // Don't work in IE
```

Yes, we can use `document.title = 'xxxx';` to change the title conent.

Comment: you can do this using `$('title').html("new title");` too

Comment: Are you asking specifically why it doesn't work? Or are you asking for a solution on how to make it work?

Comment: You've already given the solution in your question, so I'm guessing it's really about the why?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).prop('title', 'Some Text!');
```

Here to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897005/cannot-access-documents-title-element-with-jquery-ie-8) your original question. It's a known bug.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: The question asks why it doesn't work in IE, not how to do it another way. Although it may be that the OP is trying to ask for another way

Answer (score 1):

[`title.innerHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/html) is read-only in IE. Also looks like [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) has some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('title').text()); // empty in IE <= 8
```

The reason why this happens is because the page title is somewhat special in Internet Explorer <= 8; how special?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild; // null
```

When you use `jQuery.text()` it iterates over all child nodes of an element and concatenates their text representations to form the final result; because the `firstChild` property is `null`, this will obviously not work.

The page title is available as `innerText` and `innerHTML` properties, but attempting to write those properties will cause an "unknown" runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use as much jQuery as you can,

```
$("title").innerHTML = $("title").attr("text", "New title");
```

works on IE8.

> Using the `document.title` property is the simple cross-browser way to set or retrieve the document title. IE just doesn't want to play right

Comment: Doesn't works both in IE and FF, thank you for giving me some new idea

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
document.title = "This is new title.";
```

Comment: how this answer gets up votted....OP already mentioned he can do this using `document.title` OP want to know why that not working..