# Why doesn't IE8 like this JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

IE8 has been throwing this error at me

> SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
>   load-scripts.php, line 4 character 25690

I removed a .js file from the code, and the error went away. I started commenting functions out, and narrowed it down to this one. With this one commented, I don't get the error. With it active, I do get it

```
$("title, .ab-item").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("RepAgent", "Review Scout");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

I've used JSHint and it says that it's valid?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are u loading?

Comment: Which of those three lines causes the error?

Comment: What type of element is $(".ab-item") ?

Comment: does the error go away if you just try $(".ab-item").each(function() ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - 1.9.x

Comment: @Nick - it's a div. And I'm sure it would, but I got it fixed with Pointy's answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Internet Explorer doesn't like you messing with `<title>` element contents. That's not really how you set the document title anyway; just set `document.title`.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not totally 100% sure, but something in the reptile part of my brain recognizes that as an IE danger sign.

Comment: I recognize IE as a danger sign. I found this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897005/cannot-access-documents-title-element-with-jquery-ie-8.

Comment: Ahh, that was it! Thanks :)  (will accept when it lets me :D)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses `appendChild` inside `$.text()` .

Although `<title/>` has a `appendChild`-method(inherited from `HTMLElement`), this method may not be used.(it's also [not listed in the `title`-methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))